# Wireshark C arrays

Tags: wireshark, tcpreplay

I have just downloaded the latest update of **wireshark** (version 2.0.1).
This new version has an annoying feature, when I follow a specific stream and save it as C arrays, it inserts a comment line in the first row of the file:
/* Packet 8 */ 
This line interferes the work of TCP replay tool.
How can I disable this feature (without removing this line manually)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running the same version of Wireshark and have no problems with [Tcpreplay](http://tcpreplay.appneta.com/). It is probably an issue with Tcpreplay being compiled with an older version of libpcap. Older libpcap versions do not support newer "pcap-ng" format packet captures.

As a workaround, try saving your traces in older "pcap" format. Otherwise download the [latest version of Tcpreplay](https://github.com/appneta/tcpreplay/releases) and compile with a new version of [libpcap](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap).